# Installing zend-server php 5.3 on debian 7.x using chef cookbook

Tags: debian, php, debian-wheezy, chef, zend-server

When trying to install zend server ([6.3](http://www.zend.com/en/support-center/support/php-long-term-support)) with php5.3 on debian 7.x (wheezy) using the [zendserver cookbook](https://github.com/zend-patterns/ZendServerChefCookbook) for [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) I get the following error: *(needs to be php5.3 because of old code in PHP application)*

```
==> default: [2014-12-13T16:36:23+00:00] INFO: Starting install for package zend-server-php-5.3
==> default:
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[zend-server-php-5.3]'
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default: ------------------------------------
==> default: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
==> default: ---- Begin output of apt-get -q -y install zend-server-php-5.3=6.3.0+b41 ----
==> default: STDOUT: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
==> default: requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
==> default: distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
==> default: or been moved out of Incoming.
==> default: The following information may help to resolve the situation:
==> default: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> default:  zend-server-php-5.3 : Depends: zend-server-php-5.3-common (= 6.3.0+b41) but it is not going to be installed
==> default:                        Depends: libapache2-mod-php-5.3-zend-server(>= 5.3.21) but it is not going to be installed
==> default: STDERR: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
==> default: ---- End output of apt-get -q -y install zend-server-php-5.3=6.3.0+b41 ----
==> default: Ran apt-get -q -y install zend-server-php-5.3=6.3.0+b41 returned 100
==> default: Resource Declaration:
==> default: ---------------------
==> default: # In /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/zendserver/recipes/default.rb
==> default:
==> default:  65: package package_name do
==> default:  66:   :install
==> default:  67:   notifies :restart, 'service[zend-server]', :immediate
==> default:  68: end
==> default:  69:
==> default:
==> default: Compiled Resource:
==> default: ------------------
==> default: # Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/zendserver/recipes/default.rb:65:in `from_file'
==> default:
==> default: apt_package("zend-server-php-5.3") do
==> default:   action :install
==> default:   retries 0
==> default:   retry_delay 2
==> default:   default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:   package_name "zend-server-php-5.3"
==> default:   version "6.3.0+b41"
==> default:   timeout 900
==> default:   cookbook_name :zendserver
==> default:   recipe_name "default"
==> default: end
==> default: [2014-12-13T16:36:23+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default: [2014-12-13T16:36:23+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2014-12-13T16:36:23+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2014-12-13T16:36:23+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2014-12-13T16:36:23+00:00] ERROR: apt_package[zend-server-php-5.3]
 (zendserver::default line 65) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
==> default: ---- Begin output of apt-get -q -y install zend-server-php-5.3=6.3.0+b41 ----
==> default: STDOUT: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
==> default: requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
==> default: distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
==> default: or been moved out of Incoming.
==> default: The following information may help to resolve the situation:
==> default:
==> default: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> default:  zend-server-php-5.3 : Depends: zend-server-php-5.3-common (= 6.3.0+b41) but it is not going to be installed
==> default:                        Depends: libapache2-mod-php-5.3-zend-server(>= 5.3.21) but it is not going to be installed
==> default: STDERR: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
==> default: ---- End output of apt-get -q -y install zend-server-php-5.3=6.3.0+b41 ----
==> default: Ran apt-get -q -y install zend-server-php-5.3=6.3.0+b41 returned 100
==> default: [2014-12-13T16:36:23+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

It looks like this command is being executed:
`$ apt-get -q -y install zend-server-php-5.3=6.3.0+b41`

And it gives this output:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zend-server-php-5.3 : Depends: zend-server-php-5.3-common (= 6.3.0+b41) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libapache2-mod-php-5.3-zend-server (>= 5.3.21) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm stuck here and don't know what to do. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

not too certain this is still applicable but we had quite an issue installing zend 5.3 server on wheezy.  We got it running after much fudging but ended up in a situation where the SSL libs were invalid and had to run apache with non ssl sites!

If you're still after a solution my advise would be to add these to your /etc/apt/soruces.list and install the squeeze php 5.3 stack (it works quite well).

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free

HTH